# Silex : Simple Authentification Users

Tags: php, mysql, silex

I develop at present an application under the framwork Silex. I shall like using a system of authentification but I am novice on this framwork and I does not still understand everything even if I am to dive into the documentation for several days...

My application is very basic. The root is a page of connection, where user have to connect, then, according to their type (3 type of user) on the MYSQL database are to redirect towards one of the 3 pages thus, under the path /home.

**Composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "fabpot/silex-skeleton",
    "description": "A pre-configured skeleton for the Silex microframework",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "silex/silex": "~2.0",
        "silex/web-profiler": "~2.0",
        "symfony/asset": "~2.8|^3.0",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "~2.8|^3.0",
        "symfony/class-loader": "~2.8|^3.0",
        "symfony/config": "~2.8|^3.0",
        "symfony/console": "~2.8|^3.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "~2.8|^3.0",
        "symfony/debug": "~2.8|^3.0",
        "symfony/finder": "~2.8|^3.0",
        "symfony/form": "~2.8|^3.0",
        "symfony/monolog-bridge": "~2.8|^3.0",
        "symfony/process": "~2.8|^3.0",
        "symfony/security": "~2.8|^3.0",
        "symfony/translation": "~2.8|^3.0",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "~2.8|^3.0",
        "symfony/validator": "~2.8|^3.0",
        "doctrine/dbal": "~2.2"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.0.x-dev"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "run": [
            "echo 'Started web server on http://localhost:8888'",
            "php -S localhost:8888 -t web"
        ]
    }
}
```

**App.php**

```
<?php

use Silex\Application;
use Silex\Provider\AssetServiceProvider;
use Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider;
use Silex\Provider\ServiceControllerServiceProvider;
use Silex\Provider\HttpFragmentServiceProvider;

$app = new Application();
$app->register(new ServiceControllerServiceProvider());
$app->register(new AssetServiceProvider());
$app->register(new TwigServiceProvider());

$app->register(new HttpFragmentServiceProvider());
$app['twig'] = $app->extend('twig', function ($twig, $app) {
    // add custom globals, filters, tags, ...

    return $twig;
});

return $app;

?>
```

**Controllers.php**

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

//Request::setTrustedProxies(array('127.0.0.1'));

# Configuration Database
require '../web/php/bd.php';

# DAO
require '../web/model/DAO/UtilisateurDAO.php';
require '../web/model/DAO/QuestionDAO.php';
require '../web/model/DAO/PartieDAO.php';
require '../web/model/DAO/ScenarioDAO.php';
require '../web/model/DAO/RessourceDAO.php';
require '../web/model/DAO/ReponseDAO.php';
require '../web/model/DAO/SiteDAO.php';
# DTO
require '../web/model/DTO/UtilisateurDTO.php';
require '../web/model/DTO/QuestionDTO.php';
require '../web/model/DTO/PartieDTO.php';
require '../web/model/DTO/ScenarioDTO.php';
require '../web/model/DTO/RessourceDTO.php';
require '../web/model/DTO/ReponseDTO.php';
require '../web/model/DTO/SiteDTO.php';

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider());

$app->before(function ($request) {
    $request->getSession()->start();
});


$app->get('/', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
  return $app['twig']->render('index.html.twig', array());
});

$app->post('/accueil', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
  # Some Code...

    switch () {
      case '#':
        return $app['twig']->render('accueil_joueur.html.twig', array());
        break;

      case 'Admin':

        return $app['twig']->render('accueil_admin.html.twig', array());
        break;

      case 'Jury':
        return $app['twig']->render('accueil_jury.html.twig', array());
        break;

      default:
        return $app->redirect('/');
        break;
    }
});

$app->error(function (\Exception $e, Request $request, $code) use ($app) {
    if ($app['debug']) {
        return;
    }

    // 404.html, or 40x.html, or 4xx.html, or error.html
    $templates = array(
        'errors/'.$code.'.html.twig',
        'errors/'.substr($code, 0, 2).'x.html.twig',
        'errors/'.substr($code, 0, 1).'xx.html.twig',
        'errors/default.html.twig',
    );

    return new Response($app['twig']->resolveTemplate($templates)->render(array('code' => $code)), $code);
});
```

By where to begin to exploit the system of SecurityServiceProvider to propose by Silex?

Regards.

Comment: Just a reminder, [Silex will reach EOL on June 2018](http://symfony.com/blog/the-end-of-silex)

Comment: Reply to the above comment: Silex now supports Symfony 3.4 and 4.0 and is being transitioned for an easier upgrade to Symfony.

On the question, it seems quite generic, I'll recommend starting from the documentation on the security provider https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/providers/security.html and the related security component.

Comment: @HaralanDobrev I just saw the two comments on this post and I maybe have a stupid question, but Silex app/website will still works, right? I'm working on a Silex website right now and I'd like to know if it will become obsolet or not?

Comment: @MickaelLeger Apparently, with the arrival of Synfony 4 Silex will be abandoned but you can still use it

Comment: And to anwser to @Victor question : 1/Read the documentation and install the SecurityServiceProvider to your app, 2/ Use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface for your User class, 3/ Param what you want (firewall, role_user, etc) then 4/ In your controller you can check the current user_role `eg : if ($app['security.authorization_checker']->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN'))` to do what you want, and in your template you can do the same `eg : {% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %} // do somehting {% endif %}`